# Change of double integral limits

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find $\iint_{D}e^{-4x^2-y^2}dxdy$, where

$D = \{(x,y) \mid 4x^2 + y^2 \leq 2 \}$. I have to use the change of variables:

$x=ucos(v), y=-2usin(v)$.

I am able to find the new integrand, but how do I find the new limits? In the old integral I understand that $\iint_{D}e^{-4x^2-y^2}dxdy = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}e^{-y^2}dy\int_{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(2-y^2)}}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(2-y^2)}}e^{-4x^2}dx$, but how can I derive the new limits from these old ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u^{2}=\frac {4x^{2}+y^{2}} {4}$. $v$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $u$ from $-\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ to $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$. [$D$ is the region inside an ellipse centered at the origin].

Comment: So because the u-limits are symmetric and the 'new' integrand $2ue^{-4u^2}$ is an odd function, the double integral is zero? I got this but symbolab says otherwise

Comment: When you change the variable from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ you have to multiply by the **absolute value** of the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives. So the new integrand is $2|u|e^{-4u^{2}}$.